# Error message does not appear if input value is just blank space

Tags: javascript, html, input, requiredfieldvalidator

If `input` value is empty my JS function returns `false` when I click on `submit` button. However if `input` is just blank space `"    "` it's still returning `false` but the error message and `input text border color` do not showing up like they do when input value is empty `""`.

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <input id="textbox" type="text" required/>
  <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var input = document.getElementById("textbox").value.trim();

if (input.length == 0) {

    return false;
}
```

Comment: and how do you trigger your javascript? where the code that changes the colours, etc?

Comment: @JonasGrumann that's meaningless - it's already being trimmed and in any case you're running replace() on a number (the length of the input string)!

Comment: Please, if you're going to include a runnable snippet, run it before posting to make sure it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use **'pattern'** attribute and specify a regex expression for at least a single character.

Try

```
<input id="textbox" type="text" pattern="^\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$" required/>
```

The above pattern

- Zero or more ASCII digits
- One alphabetic ASCII character
- Zero or more alphanumeric ASCII characters

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually doing the validation. First validation is made when you're using the HTML5 `required` attribute. So you don't actually use the JS code. I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```js
function checkInput(){
  var input = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
  if (input === '') {
      document.getElementById('error_message').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('textbox').style.borderColor  = '#F00';
      return false;
  }else{
      document.getElementById('error_message').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('textbox').style.borderColor  = '#000';
  }
}
```

```css
#error_message{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form method='post'>
  <input id="textbox" type="text"/>
  <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Save" onclick='checkInput();'/>
  <p id='error_message'>
  error message
  </p>
</form>
```